# How to set variable in routes - laravel

Tags: php, variables, get, routes, set

I have the following route in my routes.web.php. Looks like this...

```
Route::get('/spielerAuswahl/{somevar}', 'SpielplanController@getHeimGast');
```

In the variable {somevar} I have for example Nr1=111&Nr2=222. The route works fine in a get to SpielplanController...

```
public function getHeimGast(){
        $var = $somevar;
        return view('test')->with('variableControllerSomevar', $var);
    }
```

In this function I want to put the Nr1=111&Nr2=222 in the $var and make then an easy output of this variable in the view. How to get that?

Comment: public function getHeimGast($somevar) will set $somevar to whatever is passed to the route

Comment: `Nr1=111&Nr2=222` is a query string. I doubt you can have this var as a route parameter.

Comment: And what would by the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: Either create route with parameters or access with `$request`

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer come late, but you can put `Nr1=111&Nr2=222` as uri with proper encoding. For javascript, `encodeURIComponent` can be used to escape certain characters to form a valid URI:

```
encodeURIComponent('Nr1=111&Nr2=222');
// output: Nr1%3D111%26Nr2%3D222
```

To request server, using this url:

```
http://example.com/spielerAuswahl/Nr1%3D111%26Nr2%3D222
```

The controller function then receives correct form of variable as follows:

```
public function getHeimGast ($somevar) {
    $somevar // = Nr1=111&Nr2=222
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Only URI segments can be map as route variables in Laravel, no query string variables.

You can simply fetch those like these:

```
public function getHeimGast(){
    $vars = request()->all();

    return view('test', $vars);
}
```

In your test blade, you can use those query vars, eg( Nr1=111&Nr2=222 ) as:

`$Nr1`, `$Nr2` ... and so on...

NOTE: given a query like this: `/spielerAuswahl?Nr1=111&Nr2=222`

Comment: But what does request()->all() do? all() from what? It doesn't work?!

Comment: `request()->all()` will return an assoc array of all query string params

Comment: I get undefined Variable. Did i Need a ? In my Query Or is spielerAuswahl/Nr... ok